# If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_{n} = \infty$, prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{S_{n}} = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I have no idea how to go about this and I have been stuck on it for 3 days.
The formula we have for infinite limits is:

For every $M>0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n > N \implies S_{n} > M$.

The only thing that came to my mind is to replace $M$ with $K=M^{2}$, then take the square root of both sides and get $\sqrt{S_{n}}>M$. But I am not sure if its 'allowed'.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, now fix $\bar M$ then we need to show that $\exists \bar n$ such that $\forall n\ge \bar N$

$$\sqrt{S_n}\ge \bar M \iff S_n \ge \bar M^2$$

then it suffices to consider $M=\bar M^2$ and $\bar N = N$.

Answer (score 0):

There exists $m$ such that $S_n >\sqrt M$ for $n >m$. Hence $S_n^{2} >M$ for $n >m$.

Answer (score 0):

$\fbox{For every $M>0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n > N \implies S_{n} > M$.}$

Let $M$ be arbitrary and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>N$, $S_n > M^2$. Then for $n>N$, $\sqrt{S_n} > M$

---

If you want to be really verbose, you could say:

Let $M$ be arbitrary. By supposition, there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$, $S_n > M^2$. Therefore, for $n>N$, $\sqrt{S_n} > M$, completing the proof.